# GPS conversion from degrees and radians

Tags: gps

Would you please tell me how I can transform GPS data collected in the degrees and radians representation i.e 0°05'01.9"S 34°46'27.5"E to this format -0.083853, 34.774315.

Comment: There are lots of options, including online, free and paid. Do you have a language or tool in mind? What have you looked at? What have you tried? The math is trivial - you could easily do it with a calculator; but I guess you have something else in mind. We can't tell that from the question though, so you need to edit the question to explain it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use formula sheet in excel to transform to decimal degrees.[image: Excel to transform to Decimal Degrees]

In the formula bar,TYPE"=B2+(C2+(D2/60))/60" beneath DD(X) and DD(Y).

Try using your excel and represent it like the image above and use.